# Question about default UISplitView iPad app template

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Create default iPad split view based apps from template from xcode 4, then we have codes like

```
@synthesize popoverController=_myPopoverController;
```

in file DetailViewController.m

My question is

what is "_myPopoverController" ? We do not declare such attribute in the interface, why introduce this magically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Objective-C Programming Language Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) says this:

> For the modern runtimes (see “Runtime
>   Versions and Platforms” in Objective-C
>   Runtime Programming Guide), instance
>   variables are synthesized as needed.
>   If an instance variable of the same
>   name already exists, it is used.

That means the instance variable `_myPopoverController` (or whatever name you put here) will be considered as if you would declare it in the @interface section.

Comment: Personally I found this quite confusing and the only reason to do so is when you want to prevent using the instance variable directly in subclasses